# Codeigniter: Needs to click submit button twice for Data to refresh

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this simple site that selects records from a database table.

It works fine, however, when i change the user_input (date fields) and hit submit, it won't change the data unless I hit submit again then it shows the correct data as per new whereclause(date fields).

Here's my code:

View (header) -

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick-"window.location.reload()">
    <?php 
$_SESSION['fromd'] = $fromd;
$_SESSION['tod'] = $tod;
echo $fromd; 
echo $tod;
?>
```

Controller -

```
private function rp_reach_rate_get_data()
{
$this->load->model('db_model');
$result = $this->db_model->rp_reach_rate_stmt();
return $result;
} 

public function rp_reach_rate()
{

$this->load->model('db_model');
$data['sqlstmt'] = $this->rp_reach_rate_get_data();
$data['camplist'] = $this->vici_campaigns_get_data();
$data['lists'] = $this->vici_lists_get_data();
$data['shifts'] = $this->vici_shifts_get_data();
$this->load->view('header',$data);
$this->load->view('RP_ReachRate',$data);
}
```

Noting that the query works fine. It's just that, it seems that either the controller or the db_model won't refresh along with the page to reflect the data on 1st click.

Thanks,

Comment: why you are using `submit` and `onClick="window.location.together"` together? Instead of you can simply `submit` the form and in that function you can put `redirect` method where you want to redirect after submitting the form.

Comment: I have removed the onClick method.

So, my form looks like this:
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo      htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">

even if doing so, i still need to click twice for the select results to propagate with the new whereclause value.

Comment: what's the error you are getting ? and can you post a code where you submit your form

Comment: There's no error, it's just that, when there's a change in the date input field and I hit SUBMIT, expectation is that the Data table on the body should automatically refresh given that the whereclause is `select * from table where date = date_input_field`

The page refreshes retaining the field value, however, it won't do so unless I hit the submit button again. 

header.php -
`<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
---stuff---
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></form>`

The data inside the form is declared as SESSION after.

Answer (score 0):

add set_value function to your inputs and it'll work fine
ex

```
<input type="email" name="email_input" value="<?=set_value("email_input","")?>" />
```

Comment: Hi abanoub,

Ill try this out.